# Paypal sandbox to original Paypal

Tags: paypal

I used Paypal sandbox to test my code and my IPN is working.

Now, I need to go to my original Paypal account. My confusion is in sandbox, we make buyers' and sellers' accounts. And we get tit_789456613_biz@yahoo.com like seller account.

Is it needed in original account? If needed, how to make it?

If not needed, which email address should I use? Client's email or client's Paypal contact?

Comment: 1.in which account money is deducted and in which it transfer?

Answer (score 2):

When you switch over from sandbox to real service you use your own real PayPal account as seller/business.

Example:

```
<input name="business" value="you@domain.com" type="hidden">
```

And you change the form action from https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
```

Comment: 1.in which account money is deducted and in which it transfer?